# How to cycle through an enum indefinitely but NOT in a for loop?

Tags: c#, enums, mschart

I'm using the .NET `System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting` types and want to assign a `MarkerStyle` to each Series I create preferably skipping `MarkerStyle.None`, but getting the next one each time and cycling around to the beginning again.

```
private MarkerStyle markers = new MarkerStyle();

public Series CreateSeries(string name)
{
    var s = chart1.Series.Add(name);
    s.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Point;
    s.MarkerSize = 7;
    s.MarkerStyle = Cycle(markers ,MarkerStyle.None); // get next marker style
    s.XValueType = ChartValueType.DateTime;
    return s;
}
```

I tried variations of the following code I found, all of which don't compile:

```
public static IEnumerable<T>Cycle<T>(IEnumerable<T> iterable,<T> skip)
{
    while (true)
     {
        foreach (T t in iterable)
        {
            if(t == skip)
            continue;
            yield return t;
        }
    }
}
```

Gives error

> CS0411. The type arguments for method
>   'MyClass.Cycle(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable)' cannot
>   be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments
>   explicitly.

Although I have a specific use it would be nice for a generic answer.

Edit: Having looked at the code above more closely and I see it was never going to work outside a foreach loop. Ho hum. Time to write a hack:

```
private int _markerIter = 0;
private readonly int _markerCount = Enum.GetValues(typeof(MarkerStyle)).Length; 
public MarkerStyle Cycle()
{
    if (_markerIter + 1 == _markerCount)
    {
        _markerIter = 1; //skips MarkerStyle.None which is == 0
    }
    else
    {
        _markerIter++;
    }

    return (MarkerStyle) _markerIter;
}
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your Cycle method - the problem is when you're calling it, your first argument is an instance of MarkerStyle, not an enumerable of MarkerStyle

Comment: Thanks Martin I tried MarkerStyle but that gave a compiler error too. So an enum is not enumerable?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
   Enum.GetValues(typeof(T))
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.getvalues%28v=vs.110%29.aspx